# Pass arguments to command in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Is it possible to run a command in a variable and pass parameters? Given that this command requires input arguments.

Example:

```
// in launch.json
{
    "program": "${command:somecommand(foo=${someargument})}"
}
```

Comment: That's a bit vague, what kind of command? A VSCode command? A shell command?

Comment: I'm making my own commands via ego power-tools. And also there are a couple of commands coming from other libraries, like cmake-tools. `${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}` for example doesn't need arguments, but there are commands that require some input from the user before they can run.

Answer (score 0):

Create an input in your `launch.json` which calls your command, there you can pass your argument. You can then reference the input in your attach/launch config.

```
// launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "commandInput",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "somecommand",
            "args": {
                "foo": "${someargument}"
            }
        }
    ],
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${input:commandInput}"
        }
    ]
}
```